# got error when trying to output object's property

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
person = new Object()
person.name = "Tim Scarfe"
person.height = "6Ft"

person.run = function() {
    this.state = "running"
    this.speed = "4ms^-1"}

var obj = new person();
alert(obj.name);
</script>
```

Question:

In console log, it shows "TypeError: person is not a constructor", so what is the problem with above script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator calls a constructor function to create a object instance. ie a constructor needs to be an `function`, in your case Person is an object instance.

You can use the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) property of the constructor for creating shared objects.

You can rewrite it as

```
function person(){
    this.name='';
    this.height='';
}

person.prototype.run = function(){
    this.state='';
}
var obj = new person();
alert(obj.name);
```